# Xcode 7.3.1 from the App store keeps freezing on compiling

Tags: ios, xcode

I am running `Xcode 7.3.1` on my `MacBook pro 13 2015` model and suddenly this happens whenever I compile my app `Xcode` stuck at compiling source files in `Objective-C` and then freezes and crashes that if you could help me this?

Comment: Hello Aryan and welcome to Stack Oveflow. Could you post a debug output or specify, what's that error that makes troubles

Comment: Do you also have the Beta version installed? If so, that might be the reason - they seem to share some modules / libraries and if they interfere, one of them might crash